# Does mysql take into account the sequence of WHERE clauses?

Tags: mysql

I mean if we have

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE clause1 AND clause2 AND clause3
```

Does mysql skip nth record if clause1 is false without verifying clause2 and clause3?

Comment: It should skip if `clause1` is false!

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

An ADD operator requires that they all be true.

If you want to look for ANY of those 3 clauses to be true you should use OR's.

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE clause1 AND clause2 AND clause3
```

Will only return a TRUE AND TRUE AND TRUE situation

Whereas:

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE clause1 OR clause2 OR clause3
```

Will return

- TRUE AND TRUE AND TRUE
- FALSE AND TRUE AND TRUE
- TRUE AND FALSE AND TRUE
- TRUE AND TRUE AND FALSE
- TRUE AND FALSE AND FALSE
- FALSE AND TRUE AND FALSE
- FALSE AND FALSE AND TRUE

So to answer your question, if you use and add operator it will automatically disqualify a result if the first one is false, but that's because it doesn't matter what the next two are. If you use an OR operator, then it won't disqualify a result until it's checked everything.